# String Tokenizer : split string by comma and ignore comma in double quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like below -

> value1, value2, value3, value4, "value5, 1234", value6, value7, "value8", value9, "value10, 123.23"

If I tokenize above string I'm getting comma separated tokens. But I would like to say to string tokenizer ignore comma's after double quotes while doing splits. How can I say this?

Thanks in advance

Shashi

Comment: Use a CSV parser? Regex will be a bit complex. Otherwise, post what you have tried.

Comment: A CSV parser would also let you process quoted/unquoted values uniformly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a CSV parser like [OpenCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) to take care of things like commas in quoted elements, values that span multiple lines etc. automatically. You can use the library to serialize your text back as CSV as well.

```
String str = "value1, value2, value3, value4, \"value5, 1234\", " +
        "value6, value7, \"value8\", value9, \"value10, 123.23\"";

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(str));

String [] tokens;
while ((tokens = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println(tokens[0]); // value1
    System.out.println(tokens[4]); // value5, 1234
    System.out.println(tokens[9]); // value10, 123.23
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need one line and the right regex:

```
String[] values = input.replaceAll("^\"", "").split("\"?(,|$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?");
```

This also neatly trims off the wrapping double quotes for you too, including the final quote!

Note: Interesting edge case when the *first* term is quoted required an extra step of trimming the leading quote using `replaceAll()`.

Here's some test code:

```
String input= "\"value1, value2\", value3, value4, \"value5, 1234\", " +
    "value6, value7, \"value8\", value9, \"value10, 123.23\"";
String[] values = input.replaceAll("^\"", "").split("\"?(,|$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?");
for (String s : values)
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
value1, value2
value3
value4
value5, 1234
value6
value7
value8
value9
value10, 123.23
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm allergic to regex; why not double-split as someone suggested?

```
    String str = "value1, value2, value3, value4, \"value5, 1234\", value6, value7, \"value8\", value9, \"value10, 123.23\"";
    boolean quoted = false;
    for(String q : str.split("\"")) {
        if(quoted)
            System.out.println(q.trim());
        else
            for(String s : q.split(","))
                if(!s.trim().isEmpty())
                    System.out.println(s.trim());
        quoted = !quoted;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use several approaches:

1. Write code that search for comas and maintain a state weather a particular coma is in quotes or note.
2. Tokenize by double-quote symbol and than tokenize strings in the result array by comma symbol (make sure you tokenize strings with indexes 0, 2, 4, etc., since they were not in double quotes in the original string)

Answer (score 1):

Without any third party library dependency, following code can also parse the fields as per the requirements given:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CSVSpliter {

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    String inputStr = "value1, value2, value3, value4, \"value5, 1234\", value6, value7, \"value8\", value9, \"value10, 123.23\"";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer (inputStr);
    List<String> splitStringList = new ArrayList<String> ();
    boolean insideDoubleQuotes = false;
    StringBuffer field = new StringBuffer ();

    for (int i=0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if (sb.charAt (i) == '"' && !insideDoubleQuotes) {
            insideDoubleQuotes = true;
        } else if (sb.charAt(i) == '"' && insideDoubleQuotes) {
            insideDoubleQuotes = false;
            splitStringList.add (field.toString().trim());
            field.setLength(0);
        } else if (sb.charAt(i) == ',' && !insideDoubleQuotes) {
            // ignore the comma after double quotes.
            if (field.length() > 0) {
                splitStringList.add (field.toString().trim());
            }
            // clear the field for next word
            field.setLength(0);
        } else {
            field.append (sb.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    for (String str: splitStringList) {
        System.out.println ("Split fields: "+str);
    }
}
```

}

This will give the following output:

> Split fields: value1
>
> Split fields: value2
>
> Split fields: value3
>
> Split fields: value4
>
> Split fields: value5, 1234
>
> Split fields: value6
>
> Split fields: value7
>
> Split fields: value8
>
> Split fields: value9
>
> Split fields: value10, 123.23

Answer (score 0):

```
String delimiter = ",";

String v = "value1, value2, value3, value4, \"value5, 1234\", value6, value7, \"value8\", value9, \"value10, 123.23\"";

String[] a = v.split(delimiter + "(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*+\"){2})*+[^\"]*+$)");
```