# Optimize Comma Separated Values Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, csv, quotes

I am creating a string array of comma separated values.
I need to split the line on commas but not commas that are inside quotes as that could be part of the data.

For example:
`\"421 15th Ave.\",\"Beaver Falls, PA\",\"S1\",`

I wouldn't want it to split between the city and state for a new field.

Here is the code currently:

```
string[] fields = Regex.Split(lines[i], @",(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))");
```

It takes a long time to execute.
Is there a better option I could be using?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Are you required to use regex? CSV is often best tackled using plain old `string` methods.

Comment: I am not required to use regex that is just what is currently in place.  Looking for a better option.  Which string method(s) would you suggest to solve this?

Comment: Use some sort of `csv` reader.  Assuming you're using a decent one, this will already be handled and the code should be optimized.

Comment: You might gain even more performance if you parallelize the spliting file lines between processors, using Parallel.ForEach & Parititioner.Create. This way you can process LINES0-1000 on a processor1, and LINES1001-2000 on a processor2, yielding you 2x improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a CSV-Reader?
This CSV-Reader should already handle the case of commas inside double quotes:
[OpenCsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/)

See Ravi Thapliyal's answer in this thread about how to use it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241010/string-tokenizer-split-string-by-comma-and-ignore-comma-in-double-quotes)

For C# I can recommend this CsvHelper: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

We use it in our project and it's very handy

Comment: Is there a C# equivalent to this?

Comment: Hey Baxter I updated my answer just before you commented :-)
See the CsvHelper link in my answer above

Comment: Hey Baxter if this answer helped I would appreciate, if you could mark it as accepted answer :-) thanks