# Java Print Each DB Row In New Line

Tags: java

Scenario A (Hard code)
The string items are typed in manually:

```
String[] arrayOfString = { "-25.87676, 67.78978", "-26.43545, 28.235325"};

    for (String s : arrayOfString)
        System.out.println("Line " + s);
```

System.out :

```
Line    -25.87676, 67.78978
Line    -26.43545, 28.235325
```

This works just fine as it prints each item in new line without quotes

Scenario B (Soft code) 
The string items are queried from database:

```
String[] arrayOfString = { dataFromDB };

    for (String s : arrayOfString)
        System.out.println("Line " + s);
```

System.out :

```
Line    “-25.87676, 67.78978”, “-26.43545, 28.235325”
```

This prints to a single line which is not what I want, how can I make this print like scenario A (new line for each item)

FYI..
System output of variable dataFromDB is:
    “-25.87676, 67.78978”, “-26.43545, 28.235325”

Comment: What is the type of dataFromDB?

Comment: Your database returs JSON like MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataFromDB variable seems to be a single string. You should use a regex to split it on the "," after the coordinates to get an array.

Comment: I've never used regex before, how can I go about doing so?

Comment: This is a basic tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ from the oracle documentation. When you are retrieving the data from the DB can you add it to a list instead of creating a string?

Answer (score 0):

This should work
`for(String s : arrayOfString.split(",")){
System.out.println(s);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Used the following :
.replaceAll("^\"", "").split("\"?(,|$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?");

```
String [] arrayOfString = dataFromDB.replaceAll("^\"", "").split("\"?(,|$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?");
```

Crazy code but it worked, link:
[String Tokenizer : split string by comma and ignore comma in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241010/string-tokenizer-split-string-by-comma-and-ignore-comma-in-double-quotes)